# Problems with IF-OR-ISBLANK Functionality

Tags: google-sheets

So I'm trying to use the following formula to check if either of 2 cells in a column is blank and if neither if blank that return the number of days between them and if either is blank to return an empty cell:

```
={"Consultant Turn Around";ArrayFormula(IF(OR(ISBLANK(J2:J),ISBLANK(K2:K))),,NETWORKDAYS(J2:J,K2:K,Data!B2:B))}
```

However I'm getting the error:

> Wrong number of arguments to ARRAYFORMULA. Expected 1 arguments, but got 3 arguments.

and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I think its something with how the `OR` statement works since I have a very similar formula that only checks one cell that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with brackets

```
={"Consultant Turn Around";
ArrayFormula(IF(OR(ISBLANK(J1:J4),ISBLANK(K1:K4)),,NETWORKDAYS(J1:J4,K1:K4,Data!B2:B)))}
```

However, it will return blank if there is at least one case 
This formula would return list of day differences and blank cells in case any of the dates is missing

```
={"Consultant Turn Around";
ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(NETWORKDAYS(J1:J4,K1:K4,Data!B2:B),0,""))}
```